Error in Jest: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' at Runtime.loadEsmModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:516:20)
Getting Error On Running Jest Test:
ReferenceError: You are trying to import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From test/api/agents/index.test.ts.
FAIL  test/api/agents/index.test.ts
● Test suite failed to run
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

  at Runtime.loadEsmModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:516:20)

ReferenceError: You are trying to import a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From test/api/agents/index.test.ts.
test/api/agents/index.test.ts`
test/api/agents/index.test.ts
import { NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { createMocks } from "node-mocks-http";
import { AppNextApiRequest } from "@app/types";
import { getAgents } from "@app/pages/api/agents";
import { respond } from "@app/utils/createa-api-handler";
import { expect, describe, it, jest } from "@jest/globals";

const session = {...}

describe("/api/agents", () => {
  it("should get the list of agents.", async () => {
    const { req, res } = createMocks<AppNextApiRequest, NextApiResponse>({
      session,
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    await respond(getAgents)(req, res);

    expect(res._getStatusCode).toBe(200);
  }, 6000);
});

jest.config.ts
import type { Config } from "jest";
import nextJest from "next/jest";

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: "./",
});

const config: Config = {
  verbose: true,
  preset: "ts-jest",
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>"],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/", "/.next/", "/packages/"],
  fakeTimers: {
    enableGlobally: true,
  },
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": [
      "ts-jest",
      {
        useESM: true,
        isolatedModules: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts", ".tsx"],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/emailer/"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@app/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
  },
};

export default createJestConfig(config);

test should run at least.

If I recall correctly, you need to exit jest test scripts

@mikegross can you please explain how do I need to exit jest test scripts ?

Somehting like  process.exit(1);

@mikegross basically issue is that no any test is running and giving error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
at Runtime.loadEsmModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:516:20).

Wrong, your first line of error is: ReferenceError: You are trying to import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From test/api/agents/index.test.ts. meaning that jest is already torn down when the file is imported.
